Why are my mint tokens interchaged when I create a Raydium CPMM pool
I created a CPMM pool using the aptly named mintA and mintB fields in the createPool cpmm method.
I assumed that mintA would represent the base token, my token and that mintB would represent the quote token, in this case, WSOL.
// my token
const mintA = await raydium.token.getTokenInfo(
    "3G2CB4JMa5pbLkVcMQC89vVMqSviCp5Khp62pWqeSLo9"
);

// wrapped sol
const mintB = await raydium.token.getTokenInfo(NATIVE_MINT.toBase58());

const { execute} = await raydium.cpmm.createPool({
    programId: DEVNET_CPMM,
    poolFeeAccount: DEVNET_FEE_ACC,
    mintA,
    mintB,
     
// -- snip
});

creation txHash = https://explorer.solana.com/tx/YmW5LcaRxTcjDQoCCRbpotabwtHT7omhB4dszZKu9dSmsGNaAGZkyaDZxAVecdkoWvmCa8v3cQPSJaLJYjyxFGF?cluster=devnet
I'm I correct in my assumption that mintA = base token and mintB = quote token or is it the other way around or it doesn't matter?
